# How can I check a XML file for duplicate entries with java?

Tags: java, xml

I have to write a small Java class which has to check a xml file for duplicate entries.

The XML file has a key value with a German word and an English translation. It's about 20.000 lines.

Example:

```
<properties>
<entry key="Auto">car</entry>
<entry key="Bus">bus</entry>
<entry key="Auto">car</entry>
<entry key="Haus">House</entry>
</properties>
```

How can I read/ import the file and test them afterwards for multiple entries. My code finds all elements, but not in the right order.

This is my code to read the file.

```
package translation;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class doubleTest {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try {

        File file = new File("C://GER_EN.xml");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.loadFromXML(fileInput);


        Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while(enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println(key ); //+ ": " + value
        }
        fileInput.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
}
```

}

This is my output for the above xml example.

```
Auto: car
Bus: bus
Haus: house
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: please share your output

Comment: Are you mean to find duplicate keys?

Comment: what do you mean by "but not in the right order" ?

Comment: I edited the question. Why mean? Some of the translations exist twice and if I want to cange one of them there is the chance a second translation with the old translation will be used.

Answer (score 0):

```java
final Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>();
for (final Enumeration<Object> keys = properties.keys();
     keys.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    final String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
    if (keySet.contains(key)) {
        // duplicate key!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I have a meeting now, but I will check it right afterwards.